# Vue.Js can not access Json-Data with a returned json key attribute as string - text template syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following data:

```
[...] 
 data() {
    return {
      theme: "dark",
      data: {
        ioa: [
          
          {
            title: "xyz1",
            applications: ["app1","app2","app3"],
          },

          {
            title: "xyz2",
            applications: ["app1","app2"],
          },

        ],

        applications: {
          app1:{
            name: "app1",
          },
          mastodon:{
            app2: "app2",
          },
          app3:{
            name: "app3",
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
[...]
```

```
<!--
First i loop thow the ioa array in data json object an print it with vues text template syntax
-->
<div v-for="item in data.ioa">
    {{ item.title }}

<!--
for every element i will loop again throw the applications array in this object.
-->
    <div v-for="id in item.applications>

<!--
in "id" there is a specific name, that is also the json key of the application object in data. 
But when i want to print the title my application will show nothing
-->
        {{ data.applications.id.name }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is that i can now access the "application" object, with the returned "id" in text template syntax

The browsers console says: "Uncaught TypeError: data.applications.id is undefined". I know there is a problem with "id" which is a string ... but i dont know how to solve this.

I want to get the value of "application" json object, based on the return id value from data.ioa json object

Answer (score 0):

While you inside the v-for item.applications the data should call as **id** not **data.applications.id.name**
Answer here >>> [Full Answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ardinghelli-i0qx43?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

[image]